# ClassNotFoundException: grails.validation.ConstraintFactory

Tags: mongodb, validation, grails-orm

I'm using GORM-mongodb in standalone mode:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:6.0.4.RELEASE'
```

I have domain classes like:

```
@Entity
class Module {

  String id

  String tags

  Ability ability

  Map<String,String> metrics

  static constraints = {
    metrics nullable:true
  }

  static mapping = {
    version false
  }
}
```

I'm initializing the datasources like so:

```
new MongoDatastore( config, Ability, Module )
```

At the end of the init-phaze I always see the error:

> ERROR org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer - Unable to register GORM constraints: grails/validation/ConstraintFactory
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/validation/ConstraintFactory
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run(CachedClass.java:77)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:74)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:72)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:271)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.(MetaClassImpl.java:220)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.(MetaClassImpl.java:230)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:171)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:161)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:144)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:253)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:258)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf(InvokerHelper.java:953)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newInstance(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15645)
>       at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.registerConstraints(GormEnhancer.groovy:394)
>       at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.(GormEnhancer.groovy:112)
>       at org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.MongoGormEnhancer.(MongoGormEnhancer.groovy:38)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore$5.(MongoDatastore.java:652)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.initialize(MongoDatastore.java:652)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.(MongoDatastore.java:228)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.(MongoDatastore.java:239)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.(MongoDatastore.java:330)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.(MongoDatastore.java:340)
>       at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.(MongoDatastore.java:382)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:45)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
>       at io.mozaiq.BootStrap.init(BootStrap.groovy:21)
>       at io.mozaiq.BootStrap$init.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>       at io.mozaiq.ModuleStateVerticle.start(ModuleStateVerticle.groovy:30)
>       at io.vertx.lang.groovy.GroovyVerticle.start(GroovyVerticle.groovy:64)
>       at io.vertx.lang.groovy.GroovyVerticle$1.start(GroovyVerticle.groovy:93)
>       at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:434)
>       at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:440)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.validation.ConstraintFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 54 common frames omitted

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, that one would have to add another grails dependency, like

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-validation:3.1.14'
```

then it compiles and runs properly